# A question on defining tangent vectors on a manifold and their "defining" theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, smooth-manifolds

In the appendix of Lovelock's book "Tensors, Differential Forms and Variational Principles" they give a proof of a theorem fundamental to the notion of a tangent vector on a manifold:
Part of the proof involves considering a chart $(U,h)$ defined such that $h(p)=(0,\ldots,0)$ and then choosing a function $f\in C^{\infty}_{p}$ such that $q\in U$ is in the domain of $f$, with $h(q)=(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$. They then assert that $$f(q)=f(p)+x^{j}(q)f_{j}(q)$$ where $$f_{j}(q)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{j}}\bigg\vert_{p}\equiv \partial_{j}f(p)$$
To establish this they consider a function $g=f\circ h^{-1}$ defined on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that contains the points $(0,\ldots,0)$ and $(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$. From this, I see how it follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus that $$g(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})-g(0,\ldots,0)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dt}\left[g(tu^{1},\ldots,tu^{n})\right]dt$$ However, I'm unsure how it follows that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left[g(tu^{1},\ldots,tu^{n})\right]=u^{j}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u^{j}}$$ 
Is it just that they define the functions $u^{j}:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $u^{j}(t)=tu^{j}$ where $u^{j}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, as I could see how this could work via the chain rule, but otherwise I'm a bit confused?!

In addition, I don't quite understand why they introduce a map $h:U\subset M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by $h(p)=(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$ and then consider a set of coordinate functions which they define such that $x^{i}=u^{i}\circ h:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and then $x^{i}(p)=u^{i}$? I always though that given a chart $(U,\phi)$ one defined the map $\phi :U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $x\equiv\phi (p) =(x^{1}(p),\ldots, x^{n}(p))\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and so the coordinate functions were already defined through this without the need to introduce a composition of maps?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Briefly, "yes": $g = f \circ h^{-1}$ is "$f$ in the coordinate system $h$", and $u^{j}$ is the $j$th coordinate of $h$, so the equation you ask about is just the chain rule, assuming the summation convention.

In more detail (and to address your final paragraph), $u^{j}:\Reals^{n} \to \Reals$ denotes the $j$th Cartesian coordinate, and $h:U \subset M \to h(U) \subset \Reals^{n}$ is a chart. The coordinate functions of the chart are, by definition,
$$
x^{j} = u^{j} \circ h:U \to \Reals.
$$
(Caution: Your book seems to have used $(u^{1}, \dots, u^{n})$ to denote both the coordinates of the specific point $q$ *and* the Cartesian coordinate functions on $h(U)$.)

To say "$g$ is $f$ in the coordinate system $h$" means precisely that $g = f \circ h^{-1}$, or in terms of coordinates,
$$
g(u^{1}, \dots, u^{n}) = f(x^{1}, \dots, x^{n}).
$$
The preceding equation is a mild abuse of notation; $f$ is defined on $M$, not on a subset of $\Reals^{n}$. What's meant literally is, if $q \in M$ and $h(q) = (u^{1}, \dots, u^{n})$, then the coordinates of $q$ in the chart $h$ are $(x^{1}, \dots, x^{n})$. The preceding equation should be interpreted as $(g \circ h)(q) = f(q)$, or $g\bigl(h(q)\bigr) = (f \circ h^{-1})\bigl(h(q)\bigr)$.

(Similarly, we could write $(u^{1}, \dots, u^{n}) = h(x^{1}, \dots, x^{n})$; in the chart $h$, $h$ itself is essentially the identity map!)

In the same sense,
$$
\frac{\dd g}{\dd u^{j}}(u^{1}, \dots, u^{n}) = \frac{\dd f}{\dd x^{j}}(x^{1}, \dots, x^{n}),\quad\text{i.e.,}\quad
\frac{\dd g}{\dd u^{j}} = \frac{\dd f}{\dd x^{j}} \circ h^{-1}.
$$
The calculation in question does, therefore, amount to the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do find it very confusing that the book used the same notation for the coordinate values and coordinate functions! So, is the point that $h$ maps from the manifold to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the functions $u^{j}$ then map this *n-tuple* of Cartesian coordinates to a single value which is the $j$th coordinate of the point $p\in M$. We then wish to define coordinate functions that map directly from the point on the manifold to the coordinates of that point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, hence the composite function $x^{j}=u^{j}\circ h^{-1}$?

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent, it's just that the composition is implicit in the definition with which you're familiar. :) When you write $$\phi(p) = \bigl(x^{1}(p), \dots, x^{n}(p)\bigr),$$you're thinking of $x^{j}$ as the $j$th coordinate function on $U$. That is, if $u^{j}$ denotes the $j$th coordinate function on $\Reals^{n}$, then $x^{j} = u^{j} \circ \phi$, exactly as in the "unfamiliar" definition. (By the way, welcome to MSE!) **Edit**: Yes, your edited comment is exactly right.

Comment: Sorry to reiterate, but just to check. Is it that we need a chart $\phi$ to map the manifold to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (locally), then we need another set of functions, $u^{j}$, that map from this local description of $M$ to the coordinates of particular points on the manifold?

Comment: Also, when they write $g(tu^{1},\ldots,tu^{n})$ in the integrand are they implicitly assuming that the coordinate functions $u^{j}$ are parametrised by $t$ (i.e. $u^{j}\circ\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\gamma :[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$), such that $\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u^{j}}\frac{du^{j}}{dt}$?

Comment: It might be better to think of the $u^{j}$ as the natural consequence of the way a specific mapping is written as an ordered $n$-tuple of functions: If $\phi = (\phi^{1}, \dots, \phi^{n})$, then $\phi^{j} = u^{j} \circ \phi$. For your last question, "yes": In "$g(tu^{1}, \dots, tu^{n})$", the $u^{j}$ are the specific coordinates of $q$. Your book defines $G:[0, 1] \to \Reals$ by $G(t) = g(tu^{1}, \dots, tu^{n}) = g\circ \gamma(t)$, then uses the chain rule to compute $G'(t)$. :)

Comment: Ah, I see, so the functions $u^{j}$ are in essence deconstructing the chart $\phi$ into its component functions, such that each $\phi^{j}$ is the $j$th component f$p\in M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (in analogy, the projection of $\phi$ onto the $j$th coordinate axis)?! For the last question could you consider $\gamma$ to be a line segment joining $0$ and $u=(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})$, such that $\gamma (0)=0$ and $\gamma (1)=u$, and then $h^{-1}\circ\gamma (t) = \gamma (0)+t(\gamma (1)-\gamma (0))=tu$?

Comment: Are they then slightly abusing notation (if what I've put at the end of my last post is correct), i.e. we let $h^{-1}\circ\gamma (t)=u^{1}(t),\ldots,u^{n}(t))$, where $u^{i}(t)=u^{i}\circ\gamma (t)=tu^{i}$ (with $u^{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$? If this is this case, it then makes sense to me that $\frac{dg\circ\gamma}{dt}=\frac{du^{i}(t)}{dt}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u^{i}}$.

Comment: "Yes" to everything in your last two comments. :)

Comment: Great, thanks very much for all your help, it's much appreciated! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. :)